# Facebook - sharing a list with custom pics

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-sharer

I have a list of  facts

I want people to be able to share each individual fact with a custom pic.

Is this possible?

Looked at sharer but it does not seem to work any more it jsut seems to use the url and not the other parameters.

```
 <a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&amp;
              p[url]=http://google.com&amp;
              p[images][0]=http://myimage.png&amp;
              p[title]=This is the title&amp;
              p[summary]=This is the summary">
              <img src="img/button-facebook-like.png" alt="Facebook like" />

              </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible to share a specific URL nowadays, Facebook takes the Open Graph tags of that URL for the title, description and image.

Open Graph tags: http://ogp.me/